# why are my for loops not working for terrain generation? (unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Tring to make some terrain generation for a small world, but for loops aren't working could you please point out where I have went wrong,
[this keeps coming up on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGLjE.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResourcedOnLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int TreeX = 0;
    private int TreeY;
    private int TreeCount = 10;

    int StickX;
    int StickY;

    int RockX;
    int RockY;

    for (int i = 0; i<TreeCount; i++)
    {
        // Code to be repeated.
    }
}
```

Iv looked at several tutorials but none of them have the same problem as me and all use a similar kind of loop layout.

Comment: Because you cannot put loops outside of methods

Comment: is there a way around it or do i put it in a function and call it on void Start

Comment: It has to be in *some* method. What method that is exactly depends on how *you* want your code to behave

Comment: I strongly advise you to start by learning the basics of C#/OOP before even trying to gamedev

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a for loop outside of methods inside of a class. If you want to achieve the same thing in Unity, I'd recommend doing this in the Start() method

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResourcedOnLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int TreeX = 0;
    private int TreeY;
    private int TreeCount = 10;

    int StickX;
    int StickY;

    int RockX;
    int RockY;

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<TreeCount; i++)
        {
            // Code to be repeated.
        }
    }

}
```

Alternatively, if you want it to run every frame, use the `Update()` method

Answer (score 0):

In C# you cannot have a for-loop outside the body of a method or constructor. I believe it would be most suitable if you put that for-loop in a static-constructor. This would look something like:

```
static ResourcedOnLoad() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i<TreeCount; i++)
    {
        // Code to be repeated.
    }
}
```

You would then put this static-constructor in your ResourceOnLoad class.